# How can I localize from code behind in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, localization, win-universal-app

I've set up a resource file, and bound it so I have it working in XAML. But some elements are generated in the code behind, in the C# file of the XAML page.

In Windows Phone (non-universal app) i was able to simply call `AppResources.PROPERTY`, but what is the equivalent if I wanted to call the same in the code behind (C#) of the shared view in my universal app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this approach using [ResourceLoader](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader&ei=R8GUU5qoKtGA7Qa2uIDIDg&usg=AFQjCNHIWr27hRozykjzIxvI59vIhiGiLw&sig2=QggWWaT155HJGZSQ0pGUoQ&bvm=bv.68445247,d.ZGU). Pretty easy to use.

[A simple approach to access localized resources in Windows Store apps](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/a-simple-class-to-access-localized-resources-in-windows-store-apps/)